# Выпадающий список Android

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner, expandablelistview

Всем привет, пытаюсь реализовать такую функцию, как выпадающий список с выбором элементов как на рисунке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но не могу понять каким инструментом его реализовали. Пробовал сделать в expandable listview но listview требуется место на экране, а тут все сжато и очень удобно. Можете подсказать в какую сторону копать или подсказать готовое решение. Спиннером тоже не получается так как когда я выставляю у него в параметре layout_widh 30-60dp приложение крошится при нажатии на спиннер

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете создать свой тулбар и туда в качестве item поместить спиннер

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item

android:id="@+id/category_spinner"

android:title="@string/item_category"

app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"

app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Далее создайте макет для каждого элемента спинера

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:padding="5dp"

 android:textSize="@dimen/category_spinner_text_size" />
```

А потом работайте с ним в активити

```
public class NewsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Some code

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_news_menu_list, menu);

        createSpinner(menu);

        return true;

    }

    //Some code

    private void createSpinner(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem categorySpinner = menu.findItem(R.id.category_spinner);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) categorySpinner.getActionView();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,

            R.layout.categoty_spinner_item, Const.CATEGORY_LIST);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinner.setSelection(selectedCategory);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(changeCategoryListener);

    }

}
```

Это пример спинера из моего проекта, но я думаю тут все предельно понятно. Если будут вопросы, пишите, дополню ответ.

Comment: Спиннер создается в ActionBar и получается прокрутка элементов меню, я же хочу засунуть такой вариант в тело Activity

Comment: Ну так создайте в теле активити элемент spinner!!! Это ж вообще ещё проще